# Erro "Insert value list does not match column list" com PDO

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, pdo, crud

Ola, fiz um questionário, e ele está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
    Error: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/swdig809/public_html/class.conexao.php:2) in /home/swdig809/public_html/pesquisa/envia.php on line 35
```

acredito que seja porque alguma das perguntas são respondidas com `RADIO`

como devo estruturar o banco para salvar este tipo de dado? e como devo tratar isso no código.

Segue os arquivos:

**form.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 50px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
        <script src="../js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<form id="form-pesquisa" action="envia.php">
    <h1>Cadastro Empresa</h1>
    <label for="nome_empresa">Empresa:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nome da Empresa" name="nome_empresa" id="nome_empresa"/><br>
    <label for="nome_resp">Nome Responsavel:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nome da pessoa" name="nome_resp" id="nome_resp"/><br>
    <label for="funcao">Função:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nome da Empresa" name="funcao" id="funcao"/><br>
    <hr>
    <h2>PERGUNTAS</h2>
    <h2>A EMPRESA É:</h2><br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" id="comercio" value="comercio"/>
    <label for="comercio">Comércio</label>
    <hr>
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" id="industria" value="industria"/>
    <label for="industria">Industria</label>
    <hr>
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" id="servicos" value="serviços"/>
    <label for="servicos">Serviços</label>
    <hr>
    <br><br><hr><hr><hr><hr><br>
    <h2>SEU PUBLICO É:</h2><br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="publico" id="empresasEcomercios" value="empresasEcomercios"/>
    <label for="empresasEcomercios">Comércio / Empresas</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="publico" id="consumidorFinal" value="Consumidor Final"/>
    <label for="consumidorFinal" >Consumidor final</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="publico" id="theBoth" value="Um pouco dos dois"/>
    <label for="theBoth">Um pouco dos dois</label><hr>
        <br><br><hr><hr><hr><hr><br>
    <h2>SEU PUBLICO COSTUMA USAR A INTERNET?</h2><br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="publicoInternet" id="SimBastante" value="Bastante"/>
    <label for="SimBastante">Sim, bastante.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="publicoInternet" id="moderadamente" value="Moderadamente"/>
    <label for="moderadamente" >Sim, moderadamente.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="publicoInternet" id="naoUsa" value="Não usa"/>
    <label for="naoUsa">Não, não usa.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="publicoInternet" id="naoSei" value="Não sei"/>
    <label for="naoSei">Não sei.</label><hr>
    <br><br><hr><hr><hr><hr><br>
    <h2>QUANTOS CONCORRENTES DIRETOS VOCÊ TEM?</h2><br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="concorrentes" id="mais10" value="+ de 10"/>
    <label for="mais10">+ de 10.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="concorrentes" id="mais5" value="+ de 5"/>
    <label for="mais5" >+ de 5.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="concorrentes" id="menos5" value="Não usa"/>
    <label for="menos5">- de 5.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="concorrentes" id="naoSei2" value="Não sei"/>
    <label for="naoSei2">Não sei.</label><hr>
    <br><br><hr><hr><hr><hr><br>
    <h2>SEUS CONCORRENTES ESTÃO ONLINE?</h2><br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="concorrentesInternet" id="SimBastante3" value="Bastante"/>
    <label for="SimBastante3">Sim, bastante.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="concorrentesInternet" id="moderadamente3" value="Moderadamente"/>
    <label for="moderadamente3" >Sim, moderadamente.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="concorrentesInternet" id="naoUsa3" value="Não usa"/>
    <label for="naoUsa3">Não, não usa.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="concorrentesInternet" id="naoSei3" value="Não sei"/>
    <label for="naoSei3">Não sei.</label><hr>
     <br><br><hr><hr><hr><hr><br>
    <h2>VOCÊ COSTUMA INVESTIR EM MARKETING?</h2><br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="investirMarketing" id="SimBastante4" value="Bastante"/>
    <label for="SimBastante4">Sim, bastante.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="investirMarketing" id="moderadamente4" value="Moderadamente"/>
    <label for="moderadamente4" >Sim, moderadamente.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="investirMarketing" id="naoUsa4" value="Não investe"/>
    <label for="naoUsa4">Não, não invisto.</label><hr>
    <br><br><hr><hr><hr><hr><br>
    <h2>Se sim, qual tipo. Se não, porque ?:</h2><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Inserir texto" name="qualeporque" id="qualeporque"/>
   <br><br><hr><hr><hr><hr><br>
    <h2>SE INTERESSA PELO ASSUNTO?</h2><br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="interesse" id="SimBastante5" value="Bastante"/>
    <label for="SimBastante5">Sim, bastante.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="interesse" id="moderadamente5" value="Moderadamente"/>
    <label for="moderadamente5" >Sim, moderadamente.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="interesse" id="naoUsa5" value="Não se interessa"/>
    <label for="naoUsa5">Não, se interessa.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="interesse" id="naoSei5" value="Não sei"/>
    <label for="naoSei5">Não sei.</label><hr>
    <br><br><hr><hr><hr><hr><br>
    <h2>GOSTARIA DE CONHECER OS SERVIÇOS E PREÇOS DA SW DIGITAL?</h2><br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="proposta" id="SimBastante6" value="Pode Mandar"/>
    <label for="SimBastante6">Sim, pode me mandar.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="proposta" id="moderadamente6" value="Pode Mandar, mas me ligue"/>
    <label for="moderadamente6" >Sim, mas não tenho tempo.</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="proposta" id="naoUsa6" value="Não enviar"/>
    <label for="naoUsa6">Não, não quero.</label><hr>
    <br><br><hr><hr><hr><hr><br>
    <h2>Porque ?:</h2><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Inserir texto" name="porqueinteresse" id="porqueinteresse"/>
    <br><br><hr><hr><hr><hr><br>
        <br><br><hr><hr><hr><hr><br>
    <h2>Email ?:</h2><br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email"/>
    <br><br><hr><hr><hr><hr><br>
    <button type="submit">ENVIAR</button>
</form>
```

**CLASS.CONEXAO.PHP:**

```
<?php 
class Conexao {
    private $data = array();
    //variavel da classe Base
    protected $pdo = null;

    public function __set($name, $value){
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name){
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }

        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        trigger_error(
            'Undefined property via __get(): ' . $name .
            ' in ' . $trace[0]['file'] .
            ' on line ' . $trace[0]['line'],
            E_USER_NOTICE);
        return null;
    }

    //método que retorna a variável $pdo
    public function getPdo() {
        return $this->pdo;
    }

    //método construtor da classe
    function __construct($pdo = null) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        if ($this->pdo == null)
            $this->conectar();
    }

    //método que conecta com o banco de dados
    public function conectar() {            
        $local = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $basename = "diner210";

        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$local;dbname=$basename",
                            "$user",
                            "$pass",
                            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }
    }


    //método que desconecta
    public function desconectar() {
        $this->pdo = null;
    }

        public function select($statement){
        $pdo = $this->getPdo();  
        $sth = $pdo->prepare($statement);    
        $sth->execute();    
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();  
        return $result;
    }
}
```

?>

e **ENVIA.PHP**

```
<?php

    //inclui as bibliotecas
    require_once('../class.conexao.php');
    //faz a canexão 
    $pdo = new Conexao();



try { 
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=swdig809_pesquisa', 'swdig809_denis', '123123', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $pdo = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO empresas VALUES(DEFAULT, :nome_empresa, :nome_resp, :funcao, :tipo, :publico, :publicoInternet, :concorrentes, :concorrentesInternet, :investirMarketing, :interesse, :email)'); //Preparando os dados
    $pdo->bindValue( ':nome_empresa' , $_REQUEST['nome_empresa']); // recebendo dados do formulario
    $pdo->bindValue( ':nome_resp' , $_REQUEST['nome_resp']); 
    $pdo->bindValue( ':funcao' , $_REQUEST['funcao']); 
    $pdo->bindValue( ':tipo' , $_REQUEST['tipo']); 
    $pdo->bindValue( ':publico' , $_REQUEST['publico']); 
    $pdo->bindValue( ':publicoInternet' , $_REQUEST['publicoInternet']); 
    $pdo->bindValue( ':concorrentes' , $_REQUEST['concorrentes']); 
    $pdo->bindValue( ':concorrentesInternet' , $_REQUEST['concorrentesInternet']); 
    $pdo->bindValue( ':investirMarketing' , $_REQUEST['investirMarketing']); 
    $pdo->bindValue( ':interesse' , $_REQUEST['interesse']); 
    $pdo->bindValue( ':email' , $_REQUEST['email']); 




    $pdo->execute(); // salvando no banco
    print $pdo->rowCount(); // retorna quantas linhas foram alteradas.

     } catch(PDOException $e) { 
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();}

 header('location: index.php');

?>
```

Comment: *"Error: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column"* está dizendo que os campos com seus respectivos valores, informados na sua query, não estão batendo com os campos da sua tabela. Tem certeza que esta é a ordem certa? E aquele primeiro campo *"DEFAULT"* que você botou, está correto?

Comment: por favor, adicione o código `CREATE TABLE` da sua tabela, vai facilitar a identificação do erro

Answer (score 3):

O erro diz que o numero de valores passados é diferente do número de colunas, pode resolver isso especifique os nomes das colunas no insert.

```
insert into tabela (c1, c2, c3) values (:c1, :c2, :c3)
```

Comment: Certo, fiz isso, e o banco também estava bem diferente.. agora uma dúvida.. o `USER_ID` esta como primary e auto-increment. devo chama-lo na função também ou não? ou ao inserir uma linha no banco ele já vai gerar automático ?

Comment: Pode omitir o campo que é auto_increment na hora inserir um valor sera adicionado. @manzetti.denis